Help identifying this connector
I need to buy a few of female and male connectors like this one, but I don't know what they are called.
5 pins
They have a latch on both sides.
This connector is used in an electric scooter, to connect the rear lights (running/brake light and the turn signals.
Thanks!


I think we'll need more pictures than that.

Upvoted for the calipers though, I wish more people would do that when posting connector identification questions.

"They have a latch on both sides". Those are not latches. Those are snaps for panel mounting.

That is ubiquitous JST SM series connector, available just about everywhere.

The fact that “everywhere” is a link is delightful.
